# Move the position of the comment flag and upvote buttons

Tags: discussion, feature-request, design, user-interface, mobile-web

When I browse the content of the SE sites from my **Android Device**, it becomes really hard to upvote a comment. Whenever I try to do so, it gets clicked on the *Flag* button. After trying several times, sometimes I succeed and sometimes I don't.

To solve this problem, Stack Exchange Sites can move the position of the *Flag* button or the *Upvote* button to the right side of the comment. It will not harm anybody (desktop viewers) but will surely benefit the mobile viewers.

Please provide your approvals and disapprovals by voting, commenting and answering. And consider adding a comment if you downvote.

Comment: *Placeholder comment for testing.*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> move the position of the Flag button or the Upvote button to the right
>   side of the comment

If you move the upvote button to the right, that would mean the comment upvote count would be there too, and this would completely alter how the site looks.

Also, "splitting" the two buttons up is not ideal as they're relevant to each other and should really live together.

> It will not harm anybody (desktop viewers) but will surely benefit the
>   mobile viewers

It will because everyone is used to how it is now, and the site has no real way to tell everyone that it's been moved, which will cause frustration and a fair number of meta posts...

Also, doing this would simply 'shift' ease of use from desktop users to mobile users, unless it can be done on mobile only (I don't think it can but could be wrong).

---

There would need to be an approach to this which does not move the buttons too much, mainly not split them up.

What about a wider vertical space between them? I would imagine this could implemented on mobile only.

Comment: "the site has no real way to tell everyone that it's been moved." -- It could be put up with some design bug fixes and be put as a PSA though.

Comment: I suppose you are right. It isn't that big of a problem. You can always zoom.